# I'm not able to access variables used in GUI (lambda expression)from other class

Tags: java, javafx, lambda

I'm making a gui application using javafx that takes input from user and then computes that data in other class. I've tried making an object and accessing it but can't get it to work. I've googled and tried a lot of things like using abstract method but can't get it to work. please tell how can i access the variables( like ID,Party,VoterAge) from controller class or any other class

```
         Submit.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
                primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
         String ID = VoterIdtext.getText();
         String Party=VoteTotext.getText();
         Integer VoterAge=Integer.parseInt(Agetext.getText());
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen from your example, your variables (ID, Party, VoterAge) are described into the method and they are local variables.
When you want to use them in other classes you need to declare them in other part. For example:

```
public static String ID = "";
public static String Party;
public static int VoterAge = null;
...

  Submit.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
         primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
         ID = VoterIdtext.getText();
         Party=VoteTotext.getText();
         VoterAge=Integer.parseInt(Agetext.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SampleApp extends Application {

public class Info {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = Integer.parseInt(age);
    }
}

private TextField ageField;
private TextField nameField;
private Info info;
private Button printButton;
private Button submitButton;

@Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    VBox root = new VBox();
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    createNameField(root);
    createAgeField(root);
    submitButton = new Button("Submit");
    submitButton.setOnAction((e) -> setInfo());
    ButtonBar e = new ButtonBar();
    printButton = new Button("Print Info");
    printButton.setDisable(true);
    printButton.setOnAction((eve) -> printInfo());
    e.getButtons().addAll(submitButton, printButton);
    root.getChildren().add(e);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void printInfo() {
    System.out.println("Name: " + info.getName());
    System.out.println("Age: " + info.getAge());
}

private void setInfo() {
    info = new Info();
    info.setName(nameField.getText());
    info.setAge(ageField.getText());
    printButton.setDisable(false);
}

private void createAgeField(VBox root) {
    HBox ageBox = new HBox(10);
    root.getChildren().add(ageBox);
    ageField = new TextField();
    ageBox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Age: "), ageField);
}

private void createNameField(VBox root) {
    HBox ageBox = new HBox();
    root.getChildren().add(ageBox);
    nameField = new TextField();
    ageBox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Name: "), nameField);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}